# Traversing to another page in reactjs inside an onclick button event

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple reactjs button (Material-UI components) and I need to trigger its onclick event, inside that I call an API to the server and upon successful callback I need to transfer use to a new page, I am writing the onclick event function as follow but it doesn't work

```
import SignupPage from "views/SignupPage/SignupPage.js";
export default function MyPage(props) {
const [is_logged_in, set_is_logged_in] = useState(props.is_looged_in);
const [fname, set_fname] = useState(props.fname);
const [lname, set_lname] = useState(props.lname);
...
function goto(e){
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/')
      .then(res =>{
        if (res.status!=200) {
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok');}
return res;})
.then(res=>{
  const value=res.data.res;
  set_is_logged_in(value);
  if (value==1){
       //traverse to new page upon successful login
       var uploadScreen=[];
       uploadScreen.push(<SignupPage />);
}
})
      }
...
<Button  onClick={goto} color="primary">Evaluate</Button>
}
```

Can someone help to come up with correct codes?

Comment: Well, this looks like client-side routing. Do you you some library for routing?

Comment: No, but it is on client side and reactjs, I have edited my codes..

Comment: are you ]install react router dom or not yet

Comment: Yes, I am using react router in my index.js page..<Route path="/signup-page" component={SignupPage} />

Comment: any help on how to do this would be appreciated!